# Point CMake to proper Python header inside conda env?

Tags: python, c++, cmake, anaconda, conda

I am trying to embed Python code in C++ and use the packages in a Conda environment. I have:

```cpp
// main.cpp
#include <Python.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    Py_Initialize();
    return 0;
}
```

And in CMakeLists.txt I added:

```
find_package(Python3 COMPONENTS Interpreter Development)
```

I run cmake with my Conda env (called `venv`) active. When I try to compile I get:

```
/home/myself/.conda/envs/venv/bin/python3.7 (found version "3.7.7") found components:  Interpreter Development
```

But then when I run `make` I get: `fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory`. So I did a `locate Python.h` and I found a couple `Python.h` files:

```
/home/myself/.conda/envs/venv/include/python3.7m/Python.h
/home/myself/.conda/envs/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/include/external/local_config_python/python_include/Python.h
/home/myself/.conda/pkgs/python-3.7.7-hcff3b4d_5/include/python3.7m/Python.h
```

I tried replacing `#include <Python.h>` in main.cpp with `#include <PATH>` where PATH is replaced with one of the paths listed above. In all three cases, I get a new error:

```
undefined reference to 'Py_Initialize'
```

Could someone please point out what I am missing here? Also I do not have sudo permissions on this machine

**UPDATE:**
This question and the solution by Guillame Racicot are for cmake version 1.13.5. As Guillame noted, the solution may vary for different version of cmake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `find_package`, you also have to link it to your targets:

```
find_package(Python3 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Interpreter Development)

add_executable(main main.cpp)

# Adds the proper include directories and link to libraries
target_link_libraries(main PUBLIC Python3::Python)
```

As for the documentation on how CMake works, and how targets and imported targets works, please refer to [cmake-buildsystem(7)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html).

To know what to do when importing, refer to the documentation of that module. For example, here's the documentation for [FindPython3](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindPython3.html). There's is a list of all targets to link to and all components that can be found.

Comment: I will read through that cmake-buildsystem resource to understand this better. Right off the bat just trying this solution I still get an error `Target "main" links to target "Python3::Interpreter" but the target was not found` and same for `Python3::Module`. Any ideas about those?

Comment: Really weird. Cmake docs for FindPython3 say that it should import target `Python3::Interpreter`. I verified that `Python3_Interpreter_FOUND` is in fact true but I still get the same error saying the target was not found. What would explain this?

Comment: @thehumaneraser be sure to put `REQUIRED` as I did in my example. The package must be found if you want to use the targets. Also, be sure to look at the doc for the CMake version you currently use. Modules do change between versions.

Comment: @thehumaneraser If that still don't work then I'm not entirely sure. Delete the build directory and re-run CMake to completely flush the cache to see if it helps.

Comment: @thehumaneraser also, what CMake version do you use?

Comment: @thehumaneraser I edited the answer so that it should work with older cmake versions.

Comment: @Guillaumee Racicot this did it! It is now working and I really appreciate your help. Trying to understand it though, why would `Python3::Interpreter` not be found? The FindPython3 docs make it seem like this should be defined if the interpreter is found, which it is (as I verified). I am running cmake 1.13.5 and FindPython3 was introduced in 1.12 so I should have a new enough version...

Comment: @thehumaneraser The solution I posted worked for `v3.20`. And I realized that you don't need to link to interpreter.